# Anemone Crawler skip_links_like not obeyed

Tags: ruby, anemone

I am using `Anemone` to crawl a massive site that to make things worse has the same content on a few different language versions.

There is `domain.com/` for the main language and `domain.com/de/`, `domain.com/es/` for the other languages so I decided to exclude these in the crawl like so:

```
crawler = Anemone::Core.new('http://domain.com', opts = {skip_query_strings: true})
crawler.skip_links_like(/(.+com\/(fi|de|it|no|se|en-bm|dk|fr|ie|en-nz|es|int).*)|(\.(jpg|pdf|png|jpeg)$)/)
```

However when looking at what is being crawled via a `puts page.url` in the `on_every_page do |page|` block I can see that it is still crawling all the many language variations.

I've even tried to include this

```
crawler.focus_crawl{|page| page.links.reject{|i| !i.to_s.match(/(.+com\/(fi|de|it|no|se|en-bm|dk|fr|ie|en-nz|es|int).*)|(\.(jpg|pdf|png|jpeg)$)/).nil? }}
```

To remove the language links from what is being considered next in the list of pages to crawl.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the `skip_links_like` method takes URIs not URLs meaning you can only match on parts after the top level domian so instead of this:

```
crawler.skip_links_like(/(.+com\/(fi|de|it|no|se|en-bm|dk|fr|ie|en-nz|es|int).*)|(\.(jpg|pdf|png|jpeg)$)/)
```

I had to use this:

```
crawler.skip_links_like(/(^\/(fi|de|it|no|se|en-bm|dk|fr|ie|en-nz|es|int).*)|(\.(jpg|pdf|png|jpeg)$)/)
```

or just the REGEX differences:

Wrong: `.+com\/(fi|de|it|no|se|en-bm|dk|fr|ie|en-nz|es|int).*`

Right: `^\/(fi|de|it|no|se|en-bm|dk|fr|ie|en-nz|es|int).*`